# CakePHP: formatResults() and combine()

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

Suppose I have this `find()`:

```
    $categories = $this->Pages->Categories->find('active')
        ->select(['title', 'slug', 'page_count'])
        ->order(['title' => 'ASC'])
        ->cache('widget_categories')
        ->toArray();
```

Now, I want the `slug` field will be the array key.

For now I use a (horrible) loop:

```
    foreach ($categories as $k => $category) {
        $categories[$category->slug] = $category;
        unset($categories[$k]);
    }
```

Example of debug for `$categories`:

```
########## DEBUG ##########
[
        'first-page-category' => object(MeCms\Model\Entity\PagesCategory) {

                'title' => 'First page category',
                'slug' => 'first-page-category',
                'page_count' => (int) 1,
                '[new]' => false,
                '[accessible]' => [
                        '*' => true
                ],
                '[dirty]' => [],
                '[original]' => [],
                '[virtual]' => [],
                '[errors]' => [],
                '[invalid]' => [],
                '[repository]' => 'MeCms.Categories'

        },
        'sub-sub-page-category' => object(MeCms\Model\Entity\PagesCategory) {

                'title' => 'Sub sub page category',
                'slug' => 'sub-sub-page-category',
                'page_count' => (int) 2,
                '[new]' => false,
                '[accessible]' => [
                        '*' => true
                ],
                '[dirty]' => [],
                '[original]' => [],
                '[virtual]' => [],
                '[errors]' => [],
                '[invalid]' => [],
                '[repository]' => 'MeCms.Categories'

        }
]
###########################
```

This creates two problems:

- it's a horrible method;
- the data is cached before changing the array keys, then the same cycle must be performed each time.

One possible solution is to use `Cache::read()` and `Cache::write()`. Example:

```
$categories = Cache::read('widget_categories');

if (empty($categories)) {
    //Find...

    //Loop for changing keys...

    Cache::write('widget_categories', $categories);
}
```

What seems to me the best solution, however, it is to use `formatResults()` with `combine()` methods. Example:

```
    $categories = $this->Pages->Categories->find('active')
        ->select(['title', 'slug', 'page_count'])
        ->order(['title' => 'ASC'])
        ->formatResults(function ($results) {
            return $results->combine('slug', function ($row) {
                return $row;
            });
        })
        ->cache('widget_categories')
        ->toArray();
```

It's correct? Is there a simpler method and/or makes the code more readable?

Thanks.

Comment: Seems pretty clear and simple to me...

Comment: @ndm, just a question. I understand that I can not directly use a `Collection` method, because this would return a `Collection` object, and the `cache()` method would fail. I must therefore necessarily use the `formatResult()` method, and then call a `Collection` method in its interior. Is it right?

Comment: You can use collection methods _after_ calling `cache()`. Invoking collection methods will cause the query to be executed first. Whether you you better use a result formatter, or operate on the returned data, usually depends on how you want the data to be cached, formatted, or raw.